# MySQL COUNT Distinct number of rows across several tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

Alright, this one has stumped me for about 3 hours now and I can't get it figured out.

I've got three different tables here. Table 1 carries information about accessories tied to a job. Table two carries the actual job information. Table three is basically just cosmetic information.

```
partsdata
+-------+--------+------------+
| jobid | partid | categoryId |
+-------+--------+------------+
|     0 |      2 |          1 |
|     2 |      2 |          1 |
|     2 |      4 |          1 |
|     2 |      8 |          1 |
|     2 |     33 |          6 |
|     2 |     12 |          3 |
|     3 |      1 |          1 |
|     3 |      1 |          1 |
|     3 |      5 |          3 |
|     4 |      7 |          1 |
|     4 |     12 |          3 |
|     5 |     27 |          1 |
|     8 |      2 |          1 |
+-------+--------+------------+

quotes
+-------+----------------------------+
| jobid | customername               |
+-------+----------------------------+
|     0 | Mac                        |
|     2 | Ray & Angie                |
|     3 | Jim                        |
|     5 | Ray & Angie                |
|     6 | Susan                      |
|     8 | Mac                        |
|     9 | Dick                       |
+-------+----------------------------+

category
+-------+-------------------+
| catId | category          |
+-------+-------------------+
|     1 | category_1        |
|     2 | category_2        |
|     3 | category_3        |
|     4 | category_4        |
+-------+-------------------+
```

What I *need* is a query which will spit out a list, grouped by customername, of how many quotes that customer has in the DB for each category. I.E. Query looks in the DB and sees that Mac has two jobs, all the parts in those jobs are in catid1, which means he has two jobs for category_1. Ray & Angie have 2 jobs, but they have parts in two different categories. This means that Ray & Angie have 2 jobs in category_1 and 1 job in category_3.

```
 +--------------+-------------+---------+
 | customername | category    | numJobs |
 +--------------+-------------+---------+
 |  Mac         | category_1  | 2       |
 |  Ray & Angie | category_1  | 2       |
 |  Ray & Angie | category_3  | 1       |
 |  Jim         | category_1  | 1       |
 |  Jim         | category_3  | 1       |
 +--------------+-------------+---------+
```

What I've tried so far, is pulling the data from the parts table and then joining the other tables after that, then using COUNT to get numJobs using a query like this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT q.customername, COUNT(*) AS numOrders, c.category AS category 
FROM partsdata p
INNER JOIN category c ON p.category = c.catid
INNER JOIN quotes q ON p.jobid = q.jobID
GROUP BY q.customername, c.category
```

But this is giving me the wrong count of course. I'm absolutely stumped as to how to get this. I feel that I'm just missing something stupid. Help?

Comment: SELECT  COUNT(*) AS numOrders, c.category AS category 
FROM partsdata p
INNER JOIN category c ON p.category = c.catid
INNER JOIN quotes q ON p.jobid = q.jobID
GROUP BY p.jobid  Try this hope it work for you

Comment: @AwaisUsmani That's still giving me the incorrect count as well. It seems like it's counting the individual records from partsdata instead of quotes, like I need it to. So instead of getting 2 jobs for Ray and Angie in category 1, it looks at how many parts there are and says the count is 3

Comment: select count(*) as tjobs,category.category,quotes.customername FROM partsdata
join category on partsdata.categoryid=category.catId
join quotes on partsdata.jobid = quotes.jobid
group by quotes.customername, category.catId Take this this will give u exact result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adjust your `COUNT()` to count distinct jobIDs. That way, the duplicated partIDs won't affect the number of rows counted.

```
SELECT q.customername, COUNT(DISTINCT p.jobid) AS numOrders, c.category AS category
  FROM partsdata p
  INNER JOIN category c ON p.categoryId = c.catid
  INNER JOIN quotes q ON p.jobid = q.jobID
  GROUP BY q.customername, c.category;

+--------------+-----------+------------+
| customername | numOrders | category   |
+--------------+-----------+------------+
| Jim          |         1 | category_1 |
| Jim          |         1 | category_3 |
| Mac          |         2 | category_1 |
| Ray & Angie  |         2 | category_1 |
| Ray & Angie  |         1 | category_3 |
| Ray & Angie  |         1 | category_6 |
+--------------+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: That's it! I swear I've tried doing this before and the count would only return 1 for each name but that appears to have done the trick I needed!